# Wordpress: For the theme customizer nothing is adding setting,section,control Plz help I did everything and wasted 4 hours

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I was following a WordPress course

the problem is for the theme customizer nothing is adding settings, sections, control

plz tell me if am I making some mistake I spend 4 hours trying to find the mistake
the folder structure is correct, it's showing errors If I do something wrong but it's just not showing anything in customize section of the theme

**theme-customizer.php code:**

```
<?PHP


function ju_customize_register( $wp_customize ){
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'ju_facebook_handle', [ 
        'default'   =>  ''
    ]);



    $wp_customize->add_section( 'ju_social_section', [
        'title'     =>  __( 'Udemy Social Settings', 'udemy' ),
        'priority'  =>  30,
        'panel'     =>  'udemy'
    ]);

    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'ju_social_facebook_input',
        array(
            'label'          => __( 'Facebook Handle', 'udemy' ),
            'section'        => 'ju_social_section',
            'settings'       => 'ju_facebook_handle'
        )
    ));


}
```

**functions.php file :**

```
<?php 

//setup
define('ju_mode',true);

//includes

include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/front/enqueue.php' ) );
include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/setup.php' ) );
include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/widgets.php' ) );
include( get_theme_file_path( 'includes/theme-customizer.php' ) );




//hooks


   // for scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','ju_enqueue' );
   // for navbar
add_action('after_setup_theme','ju_setup');

   //for Sidebar 
add_action('widgets_init','ju_widgets');

// for custmizer social icons
add_action( 'customize_register', 'ju_customize_register' );
//shortcodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `'panel' => 'udemy'` so your section will only display under the section `udemy` if you don't have any section with id `udemy` then your code won't show any output as it's looking for section `udemy`

so if you don't have already existed section with id `udemy` remove that panel code and your code will show the expected output in the customizer.

**TIP:** Write section code first then setting code then its controller code, then another setting for a similar section and it's the controller. It will help you understand the connection between section, setting & controller.